# How can I add a function to a class constructor from an external file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, constructor

How can I add a function to a class constructor from an external file in TypeScript? For example:

```
class SpongeHelpers{
    public html: any;
    constructor(sel) {
        if (!sel) return;
        if (typeof sel === 'function') {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', sel);
        }else if (typeof sel === 'string') {
            var selected = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
            console.log(this);
            this.html = (arg) => {
                selected.forEach((element) => {
                    element.innerHTML = arg;
                })
            };
        }

    }
    init(sel){
        return new SpongeHelpers(sel);
    }
}
```

I have this.html defined in my class constructor, but how can I define it in a file called html.ts and have it included there? I know have to do something with interfaces but I am lost after that. Anyhelp is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate some? It's hard to tell what you are asking. Are you asking how to write a class in one file, and use that class in another file?

Comment: @alex-wayne I am trying to define a class in one file, and add methods to that class from another file. So instead of defining `this.html` where my class is defined, I can deine it in another file called html.ts.

Comment: What you are talking about is [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html).  Essentially instead of `SpongeHelpers` being a class, it should be a higher-order function which takes the class which you wish to extend and returns a modified version of that class.

Comment: Alright I will look at those. Thank you!